# Can gulp-ejs be used dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, ejs

There is a project, layout of the admin panel with numerous components. There is a folder of components, to use them, I use the **gulp-ejs plugin** and do it like this: `<%- include('../components/buttons/_success') %>` Naturally, the button has the same text wherever this component is included, and **I want to make its text dynamic**, for example, I import it into the navigation and change the text. As an example, you can take a react, where instead of the static text of the component, they put some kind of props.title. Please help me how to implement this using gulp-ejs. As you already guessed, **the project is built using the gulp builder**, clean layout, **without any express-js**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I did find a way, for this you can use the "gulp-file-include":

1. Install package:

> `npm i gulp-file-include`
> 2. Import it into the gulp configuration file (in my case it is the gulpfile.js file)

> `const include = require('gulp-file-include');`

3. Use it when generating html:

> `function html() {`
>
>   `return src([sourceFolder + '/html/**.html', sourceFolder + '/html/*.htaccess'])`
>    `.pipe(include())`
>    `...` 
> `}`

4. Let's say there is a template for a button, and you want to pass text there dynamically, for this you use `@@` to declare a variable, the value of which can be changed through the parent:

**button.html:**

```
<button class="btn">@@content</button>
```

5. Now to use the button component in another file and to change its text you need to pass the second parameter when importing:

**index.html:**

```
<div>
  @@include('button.html', { "content" : "Send"})
<div>
```

*It is important to specify the correct path to the component in the first parameter*

Ready! Now you have the button text dynamically changing, for a more detailed study, here is a [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-file-include) with a library and documentation

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation (See also: [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).